# Only the the last image is uploading while trying to upload multiple image in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to upload multiple image. But the problem is only last image is getting uploaded.Here are my codes

> view

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" multiple accept="image/*">
```

> controller

```
if($request->file('file')){
            $files = $request->file;
            foreach ($files as $file){
                $fileName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file->move(public_path('/images'), $fileName);
                $Product = Products::select('product_id')->orderBy('product_id','desc')->first();
                $Photo = new Photo();
                $Photo->url = $fileName;
                $Product->Photo()->save($Photo);
            }
```

How to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, Just Select all the files at once So your Input field should display the number of images/files selected, not the last file name:
[image: Input Sample]

Comment: I was such a fool